# Simplification conditions for basic expressions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, soft-question, algorithms, education

Being somewhat a part-time educator teaching (mostly adults) basic math I find myself troubled by questions I tend to get.

Being more specific, students ask me for conditions, algorithms and other ways to determine if some expression (basic algebra or some trig stuff, as example) can be simplified into something "shorter" and "better". Except for some cases, like dividing by (x-a) for polynomials, I can't actually answer anything decent.

It seems that at the beginning (pre-calculus algebra, trig equations, limits and series, integration) a lot of math depends on technical trickery — using various short multiplication forms, conjugates etc. The problem is, despite math being a pretty rigorous field, there's no way to determine if something can be simplified and, more broadly, represented in a suitable form.

The only way to guide someone would be telling "You just have to see that!", "Do another 1000 excercises and you'll get a better feel!", "Pay more attention to details" and so on — that doesn't seem either rigorous or intuitive and leaves students discouraged and demotivated.

I'd be extremely grateful if someone could point me to some algorithm, approach, idea or concept that is capable of presenting algebraic trasnformations as something besides a strange art only being mastered by extensive practice.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This seems really broad. There are clusters of situations that you could give a tidy algorithm for, but an algorithmic approach depends sensitively on the curriculum. For example, *if* a course/textbook tests identifying "quadratics in disguise" like $\sin^6\theta+2\sin^3\theta+1=0$ then it would be helpful to write down an algorithm (or add to a big algorithm) a procedure to detect such things when they come up. And if you take a standard calculus textbook, you could probably make a big algorithm for all the antidifferentiation algebra tricks needed for *that particular text*. But in general?

Comment: Your statement "there's no way to determine if something can be simplified and, more broadly, represented in a suitable form." is exactly correct. There is no general way. Even Computer Algebra Systems can simplify only a limited extent. However, with practice, you can recognize situations where simplification techniques can likely be applied.

Comment: @MarkS. Thanks! I totally agree with you. However, we may face a tougher and more complicated expression with a goal to simplify it. Doing that, we apply many combinations  and sequences of completely legit alrebraic transformations. 

In the end we either arrive or do not arrive with an answer. And that wholely depends on the art of 'seeing things' which is hard to formalize and explain to someone who's not keen on studying all the little tricks yet. 

Practice makes perfect, sure, but it doesn't make someone motivated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In agree with you that most of the time, there isn't a step-by-step approach you can take to a problem—you have to be creative. However, there are a few things to note:

- The problems given in school often have 'nice' solutions that *can* be found by using the techniques and tricks taught in class. This will motivate students, who know that they are able to get to the answer if they persevere
- Being able to spot things is rather satisfying

For example, here was a problem that I was struggling with today:

> Assuming *only* that $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$, show that $\sin\theta\cos\theta\leq\frac{1}{2},$

There are a number of things that make this problem interesting to me:

- I know that there is a true result which *can* be found. Moreover, I know that it can be found using what I've learnt so far
- If I do connect the dots, then it is extremely satisfying, as it shows the link between different things I have learnt

Here, the key to finding the solution was realising that

\begin{align}
(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)^2&=\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta+2\sin\theta\cos\theta \\
&=1+2\sin\theta\cos\theta
\end{align}

This links the concept of adding trigonometric functions with multiplying them—a key ingredient in finding the solution! When I saw that this was the key, it did feel very satisfying. At first, it seemed like the identity $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$ was unrelated to the product of $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$, but it suddenly had become obvious what that relationship was. Rearranging the equation, we have

$$
\sin\theta\cos\theta=\frac{(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)^2-1}{2}
$$

And, I got stuck again. I say this because most of the solutions given in textbooks make the process of finding the solution seem like a simple, mechanical process. Well it is if you already have the answer in front of you! For everyone else, though, you just have to keep on trying. There was actually an elegant solution that didn't require calculus, but here is what I did:

The maximum of $(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)^2$ is when the derivative of $\sin\theta+\cos\theta$ equals $0$:

$$
\cos\theta-\sin\theta=0
\implies \cos\theta=\sin\theta
$$

This occurs when $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$. Hence, the maximum of $\sin\theta+\cos\theta=\sqrt{2}$, and substituting this back in gives the desired result. Using calculus, I got to the same answer that a clever rearrangement did. The fact that there were two equally valid approaches to this problem is also very reassuring. It shows that as long as we are doing good maths, and looking out for ways to simplify problems, then it is definitely possible to get to the answer, even if our solutions aren't mechanical. It's OK to get stuck, it's OK for your first attempt to be messy, and it's OK to not spot what you can do to simplify a problem. If you keep trying, the payoff is immense.

Comment: That's an awesome an example! Just to add something, for those scared of calculus introducing a famous trig identity would do as well: $acos(x)+bsin(x)=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}cos(\alpha - \beta)\leq \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$

Plus learning some other fields like complex numbers allows rephrasing many technical problems in terms a student may feel more confident with. 

However, the basic premise, as I see it, remains the same — you have an expression in need of simplifying through a sequence of legitimate symbolic transformations. But you have no guarantee that any of that combinations would yield the result

Comment: @user2057368 Thank you. I've only just been introduced to complex numbers, so I hadn't come across this before, but I've heard that complex numbers make trigonometry a lot easier, so I'll definitely be looking forward to learning this.

Comment: Well, complex numbers allow you to convert any trig expression into a complex number and vice versa, so it becomes a matter of preference what form to use. Basically you can now add all the exponent techniques you know in order to achieve the desired results.

Knowing that trig stuff, complex numbers and vectors are more or less the same thing, you can derive some property, say, for complex multiplication, and automatically it will hold for trig stuff and vectors. 

You can even rephrase some problems of plane geometry and find way quicker and more elegant solutions. Have fun!